# How to Show selected data from datalist into repeater on submit button?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

I have one datalist control which has some records, It also has child control checkbox named cb1 in the itemtemplate of datalist.

All I want to do is on the click of a submit button on page, all the checkboxed records should show up in the repeater down below. I managed to get the item.index value of the checked records into a array. But I don't know how to show the selected data into the repeater.

Here is an image of the page.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76v0Q.png)

My code

```
private void list_bind()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbbook", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = null;
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cb1");
        if(chk.Checked)
        {
             a = Convert.ToString(DataList1.DataKeys[item.ItemIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Html code

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="Both" Height="206px" RepeatColumns="3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyField="bookid">
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <ItemStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <ItemTemplate>
             <b>Title: </b><%#Eval("booktit")%><br />
             <b>Author: </b><%#Eval("bookaut") %><br />
             <b>Pub: </b><%#Eval("bookpub") %><br />
             <b>Price: </b><%#Eval("bookprc") %><br />
             <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" Text="Buy" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
         <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:DataList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <b>Title: </b><%#Eval("booktit")%><br />
             <b>Author: </b><%#Eval("bookaut") %><br />
             <b>Pub: </b><%#Eval("bookpub") %><br />
             <b>Price: </b><%#Eval("bookprc") %><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Comment: Simply bind the repeater to the array?

Comment: Array just contains the indexvalues of the items in datalist, don't know bind array to repeater would give me data from datalist to repeater.

Comment: If you want to pull each field, from each record, then think about what data structure you need. What about using a DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take DataListItem into a new array let's call it duplicate & remove all the index those are unchecked from it and bind it with the repeater then.

Comment: Thanks for replying, will try that. Didn't thought it that way.